# Using simplexml, how can I retrieve a sibling?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<root>
<pages>
<page>
    <title>Home</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
</pages>
</root>
```

Say I have a variable containing "Home", I want to get what's in the `<content>` sibling node,
Something like: `"Get -content- Where -title- = VARIABLE"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($xml->pages->page as $page) {
    if ((string) $page->title == 'Home') {
        return (string) $page->content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Much obliged